# Accordion - Open first entry after Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, accordion

I have a little problem with an accordion on my site. I'm showing several events in a calendar view, which is working fine. Configured it to open the first entry when the site is loading, which also works fine. The problem is, that I have several filters for showing these events (e.g. category, year, month...), calling with an AJAX request. After I used any of these filters, it's not possible to open the first event of the accordion automatically as it is, when my site is loading. Hope you could understand my problem because my English is not so good :)

**HTML for one of the filter:**

```
<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

    <select id="month-event-filter" name="month" disabled>
            <?php if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) { ?>
        <option value=""><?php _e( "Month", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
        <option value=""><?php _e( "Alle Monate", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        <option value="1"><?php _e( "January", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="2"><?php _e( "February", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="3"><?php _e( "March", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="4"><?php _e( "April", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="5"><?php _e( "May", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="6"><?php _e( "June", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="7"><?php _e( "July", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="8"><?php _e( "August", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="9"><?php _e( "Setpember", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="10"><?php _e( "October", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="11"><?php _e( "November", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
        <option value="12"><?php _e( "December", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>

    </select>
```

**HTML (PHP) of my accordion:**

```
if ($start_date_cal_m <> $prevMonth) {
// if a new year we definitely need to close the previous accordion div
// unless it's the first iteration
if ($prevDay) {
    echo '</div><!-- close accordion div 1-->';
}
echo "<h3>$start_date_cal_m_name</h3>\n";
}
if ($start_date_cal_m <> $prevMonth || $start_date_cal_d <> $prevDay) {
// if new month but not new year close accordion
if ($start_date_cal_m == $prevMonth) {
    echo '</div><!-- close accordion div 2-->';
}

echo "<button class=\"accordion\">$start_date_cal_d_name,      $start_date_cal_d.$start_date_cal_m.</button>\n";


echo "<div class=\"panel\">\n";


}
```

**Accordion Javascript:**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
}
}
acc[0].onclick();
```

**jquery filter:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery("#location-events").change(function() {
    jQuery('#my_listings_current_page').val("1");
    $.fn.tdSubmitFilter();
}); 

jQuery("#category-events").change(function() {
    jQuery('#my_listings_current_page').val("1");
    $.fn.tdSubmitFilter();
}); 

var val = jQuery("#year-event-filter").val();

if( val === "" ) {
    jQuery("#month-event-filter").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
    jQuery("#month-event-filter").removeAttr('disabled');
}

jQuery("#year-event-filter").change(function() {
    jQuery('#my_listings_current_page').val("1");
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    if( val === "" ) {
        jQuery("#month-event-filter").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        jQuery("#month-event-filter").val("");
        jQuery("#day-event-filter").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        jQuery("#day-event-filter").val("");
    } else {
        jQuery("#month-event-filter").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    $.fn.tdSubmitFilter();
});

var val2 = jQuery("#month-event-filter").val();

if( val2 === "" ) {
    jQuery("#day-event-filter").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    jQuery("#day-event-filter").val("");
} else {
    jQuery("#day-event-filter").removeAttr('disabled');
}

jQuery("#month-event-filter").change(function() {
    jQuery('#my_listings_current_page').val("1");
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    if( val === "" ) {
        jQuery("#day-event-filter").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        jQuery("#day-event-filter").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    $.fn.tdSubmitFilter();
});

jQuery("#day-event-filter").change(function() {
    jQuery('#my_listings_current_page').val("1");
    $.fn.tdSubmitFilter();
});

jQuery(document).on("click",".pagination a.page-numbers",function(e){

    var hrefprim = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var href = hrefprim.replace("#", "");

    jQuery('#my_listings_current_page').val(href);

    $.fn.tdSubmitFilter();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

});

$.fn.tdSubmitFilter = function() {

    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);

    jQuery('#td-filter-events').ajaxSubmit({
        type: "POST",
        data: jQuery('#td-filter-events').serialize(),
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        beforeSend: function() { 
            jQuery(".upcoming-events-holder").fadeOut(200);
            jQuery(".upcoming-events-holder").html("");
            jQuery(".listing-loading").css("display", "inline-block");
        },   
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery(".listing-loading").css("display", "none");
            jQuery(".upcoming-events-holder").html(response);
            jQuery(".upcoming-events-holder").fadeIn(200);  
        }
    });

}

});
```

Comment: Nobody any idea? Or is any important information missing?

Comment: Nobody here with any clue regarding to my problem? Had so much hope in writing at stackoverflow.